# Merge [gmail-contacts] and [google-contacts]

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

Not sure which way round this should go, and this would probably be a good use for synonyms. Whilst there are subtle differences between clicking the Contacts button in GMail, and going to the Contacts only web page I don't think there's enough difference to justify two tags.

[gmail-contacts] x 7 
[google-contacts] x 16

Answer (score 8):

I would favor [google-contacts].  I think [gmail-contacts] might be more familiar to users, but it isn't as accurate.  Modifications to contacts from within Gmail affects your global contacts, not just Gmail.  This is why I think [google-contacts] would be better as it is more correct.  If we merge [gmail-contacts] into [google-contacts] and then setup a tag synonym so that new questions can't be created with [gmail-contacts] I think we'd fine.

Comment: sounds good to me

Comment: For those of you that agree, I [created the synonym here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/google-contacts/synonyms), so please vote on it.

Answer (score 3):

Right now, the [Contacts product available through Gmail](http://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#contacts) is **significantly** different than the general Google Contacts ([accessible by itself](http://www.google.com/contacts/), [through Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/b/0#contacts), etc.)

So, until they are once again completely the same I'd say leave it be.

***Update***: This is still true, by the way. The Contacts app in Gmail is much different than the Contacts app available elsewhere.

Comment: Huh, when did that happen?

Comment: Circa 10-August. http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/updates-to-contacts-and-slightly-new.html

Comment: Didn't know that, wonder when that'll get to Apps accounts.

Comment: They are very different, and now that Gmail is forcing us go to to Google contacts we're really losing functionality. http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75625/disable-google-contacts-preview

Answer (score 0):

Originally they used to be two separate products, but now it seems like Google has merged the two. I think that [gmail-contacts] should be used instead of [google-contacts], since you access it through Gmail.

The only concern is for Google Apps users, but I think [gmail-contacts] is fine for them as well.

What do you guys think?

Comment: As an Apps user myself, I see no problem with which one is decided on, particularly if they are set up as synonyms.